# how to append jquery auto complete data to text field?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

Hi, I am using jquery autocomplete plugin. It works nicely, but the problem is the autocomplete data appends outside the form. It is ok when using one auto complete text box, but when using two auto complete textboxes it is very hard to get the values and do coding.

I want to append the `AutocompleteContainter` div to my text box, so then I can get the values easily.

Here is my code:

**jQuery**

```
options = { serviceUrl: "<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>index.php/welcome/autocomplete" };    
a=$('#query').autocomplete(options);

options = { serviceUrl: "<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>index.php/welcome/autocomplete" };    
a=$('#query2').autocomplete(options);
```

---

**HTML**

```
<body>

<?php echo form_open("welcome/test");?>
<fieldset>
    <div id="add-brands-container" class="hide1" style=""></div>
    <div class="clear-fix"></div>
    <input type="text" name="textbox" id="query"  style="display:block" />
    <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="query2"  style="display:block" />
    <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset> 

    <?php echo form_close();?>

</body>
```

When viewed in FireBug, `AutocompleteContainer` is added after the closing `</form>` tag:

```
</form>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 33.85px; left: 10.8833px;" id="AutocompleteContainter_32baa">
    <div class="autocomplete-w1">
        <div style="display: none; width: 115px; max-height: 300px;" id="Autocomplete_32baa" class="autocomplete">
            <div title="january" class="">j<strong>a</strong>nu<strong>a</strong>ry</div>                  
            <div title="february" class="selected">febru<strong>a</strong>ry</div>
            <div title="march">m<strong>a</strong>rch</div> 
            <div title="april"><strong>a</strong>pril</div>
            <div title="may">m<strong>a</strong>y</div>
            <div title="august"><strong>a</strong>ugust</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 53.85px; left: 10.8833px;" id="AutocompleteContainter_5c3c7">
    <div class="autocomplete-w1">
        <div style="display: none; width: 115px; max-height: 300px;" id="Autocomplete_5c3c7" class="autocomplete"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I append these two `AutocompleteContainter` div's to my text boxes? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `AutocompleteContainter` inside the form. It's purpose is to disaply autocomplete "popup" only. You have data you need inside inputs, to which you have attached the autocompletes, i.e. `#query` and `#query2`.

Comment: sooo if $('.autocomplete > div').live('click',function(){ how can i get it is from #query or #query2

Comment: You are probably doing something that you don't need. :) Why do you want to do something on `$('.autocomplete > div')`?

Comment: when $('.autocomplete > div').live('click',function() i want to add that value to another div , there are 2 different divs for 2 add two text boxes' values

Comment: @K.B Panamaldeniya-littletipz I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a formatting/styling error somewhere. Here is an example of it working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/N6DC6/1

On a live page, I get the same result: some of the code for autocomplete is appended after the closing `form` tag. This is OK; what matters is that the value populates into the text box to be submitted. This, again, leads me to believe there is an issue with formatting and/or styling.

This is based on what I read your question as: can't get it to work. But upon reading your other comments, it looks like you may have it working, but are trying to do something based on what is clicked within the autocomplete pop-up... Not sure. -u-

If so, you could add an `onChange` listener to the txt boxes and do something if a certain criterion is met.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the solution:

You need to add a select option to the instantiation of the autocomplete element:

```
        $( "#query" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui){
                    $('#div1').html(ui.item.value)
                }
    });
    $( "#query2" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags2,
        select: function(event, ui){
                    $('#div2').html(ui.item.value)
                }
    });
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/N6DC6/3/